# An API to Fetch all the ultra disk from my subscription

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, azure-disk

****Hello everyone,
Need one REST API to fetch all the ultra disks present in my subscription from the azure portal. As ultra disk has many region and size constrains we need to keep in mind all the prerequisites at the time of creation.Could not find an API meant for ultra disk specifically. Can anyone help?****

Comment: I updated my answer, pls have a check

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an ultra disk for your Azure VMs and before that, you need to know if the region and VM size support Azure constrains ultra disks, just use the PowerShell below to check:

```
$region = "<region>"
$vmSize = "<VM size>"
$values = (Get-AzComputeResourceSku | where {$_.Locations.Contains($region) -and ($_.Name -eq $vmSize) -and $_.LocationInfo[0].ZoneDetails.Count -gt 0})[0].LocationInfo[0].ZoneDetails
```

For details , pls see [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/disks-enable-ultra-ssd#determine-vm-size-and-region-availability) .

If you just want to know ultra disks present related data of your subscription , try this API :

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriotion ID>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/skus?$filter=location eq '<the location you want to check>'  &api-version=2019-04-01
```

This API will reply you all SKUs presenting information, for instance, if you want to check `southeastasia` , you will get a list below , which contains ultra disk info :

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the [`Disks - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/disks/list) API get all the disks and then pass the disk name to get the with the [DiskSKU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/disks/list#disksku)

> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks?api-version=2019-07-01